# Realm write fails on second time being called

Tags: swift, realm

I have a service for retrieving data from an api, it returns json that I map and then populate to Realm and finally display this to the view.

I have way for a user to force refresh the retrieval of data, which means I need to update my Realm data aswell. This works fine on the first time I call the method. But if I try to do it again it crashes every single time with this exception.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'
```

This is how my function works:

```
private func writeCollection(someKey: String?) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(someObject[someKey!]!, update: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred inside a different function then initially thought. I was holding a dictionary like this [someKey:someObject] and using this dictionary as a reference to write from.

Problem was this was outside the try! realm.write

```
// removed this reference
// var dictionary = [String:SomeObject]()

realm.write {
        let someObject = SomeObject()
        someObject.id = someKey
        realm.add(someObject, update: true)
}
```